# Unable to browser posts in categories

Tags: categories, errors

Hoping someone can help with this.

Clicking on a category either returns a "not found" error, or opens a random post in the category.

Verified that the issue is independent of a plugin or theme. Have also messed with .htaccess to no avail. Only works if I use the default permalink structure, which I do not want.

See these links to see the problem firsthand:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/category/tutorialstips/

http://linuxbsdos.com/category/mandriva/

TIA

Comment: I spent all day tweaking .htaccess, but that didn't seem to be the cause. My .htaccess is the same as the code snippet on that page. Funny thing is it works with the default permalink.

Comment: it looks like your category base contains just a space? `http://www.linuxbsdos.com/%20/mandriva/`

Comment: The space in the category base is not the cause. Fixed it and still does not work.

Comment: Please do not use answers for discussion. Use comments or you can add details about question by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with your htaccess or mod_rewrite on your server. Try overwriting your .htaccess with [this snippet from the Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29). Or see the mod_rewrite section that is also on that page.